# Convert iOS File Path to Cordova FilePath

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

So I am using a plugin to pick media from the iOS photo library: https://github.com/ahunter135/cordova-plugin-instagram-assets-picker

it works perfectly because it bypasses the iOS compression after media selection, the only issue is that it returns a native iOS file path like so: `file:///var/movile/Media/DCIM/100APPLE/IMG_0239.MOV`.

The plugin that is giving me trouble is: https://github.com/photokandyStudios/PKVideoThumbnail

Now it says it works with native URLs but it isn't working for me. So I am trying to find a way to convert the above file path to a cordova file path like this: `cdvfile://......`. 
I found that `cordova-plugin-file` has a system to do this:

```js
resolveLocalFileSystemURL(nativePath, function(entry) {});
```

But it always returns a NOT_FOUND_ERR for me. Does anyone have any tips and tricks for trying to convert this file path to a cordova file path?

Thanks!

I am working on an ionic 1 project.